# Visual Studio Code (VSCode) experiencing severe performance issues

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

I've been encountering significant performance issues with Visual Studio Code (VSCode) recently, and despite trying various troubleshooting steps, I haven't been able to resolve them.

**Problem Details:**

Symptoms: When using VSCode, I notice severe slowdowns, particularly when scrolling through the editor window and hovering over buttons or settings. The interface feels sluggish and unresponsive, impacting my productivity.

**System Configuration:**

Operating System: windows 11
VSCode Version: Latest version
Hardware Specifications: i7 12th gen 8gb Ram
Graphics Drivers: NVIDIA RTX 3050

**Additional Information:**

1. I haven't experienced similar performance issues with other applications on my system, suggesting that the problem may be specific to VSCode.
2. When I tried vscode in ubuntu it works very fine
3. check out my processor consumption when vs code works in back ground

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBZHn.png)

**I've already attempted the following troubleshooting steps without success:**

1. Reinstalled VSCode from scratch.
2. Reset all VSCode settings to default configurations.
3. Removed all installed extensions.
4. Removed all antiviruses

Comment: Does memory consumption stay that low? I'm assuming it will rise quickly when you use VSCode for a while. I would call 8GB of RAM just not enough for development any more.